# Apache Camel: When does property substitution in xpath expressions work?

Tags: java, xpath, apache-camel

I have the following route in Apache camel:

```
from("from.uri")
    .filter(xpath("//x:y/x:z[x:a = '{{a.property}}'")
    .setHeader("subject", 
            xpath("concat('{{another.property}}New mail (', //x:y/x:z, ')')")
            .stringResult())
    .to("{{to.uri}}");
```

However, in the call to `#filter` the substitution is not working, while in the call to `#setHeader` it is,

Is there a reason for this or did I probably miss something else?